# sed substitution: for similar regex pattern match, the substitution result is very different

Tags: bash, sed

I am using sed to replace all HTML tags in a file

Text:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have checked that basic regular expressions `<.*\?>` and `<[^>]*>` match only HTML tags in the text.

When I use `sed 's/<.*\?>//g' [input-file]`, `sed` replaces everything and five blank lines are printed, whereas, `sed 's/<[^>]*>//g [input-file]` produces the correct output and first prints two blank line, then *Hello World!* with appropriate indentation on the next line and last two blank line.

Why does it behave differently for similar matches?

Comment: Do not use `sed` for HTML text parsing, use syntax aware parsers

Comment: sed doesn't support non-greedy.. see https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions-Overview and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y